# How to make selected cell turn a different color for custom cells UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I want to make a selected cell a specific color (UIColor.systemGray). I've tried almost every answer out there but for some reason the way that my cells are it isn't working.

Here is part of my view controller class:

```
extension CommunicationViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return communicationcells.count
    }

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let communicationCell = communicationcells[indexPath.row]
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommunicationCell") as! CommunicationCell

        cell.backgroundButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.backgroundButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell.setCommunication(communication: communicationCell)
        return cell
        
    }

    
    
    struct Holder {
        static var _myComputedProperty:Int = -1
    }
    var myComputedProperty:Int {
        get {
            return Holder._myComputedProperty
        }
        set(newValue) {
            Holder._myComputedProperty = newValue
        }
    }
    


    @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        myComputedProperty = sender.tag
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "CommunicationSegue", sender: self)
        
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let detailsController = segue.destination as! CommunicationDetailsViewController
        detailsController.passthroughstring = String(myComputedProperty)
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

And here is my communication cell controller:

```
class CommunicationCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var backgroundcontentView: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var CommunicationType: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var subject: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var partnerType: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var partnerID: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var effectiveFrom: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var effectiveTo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var downtimeFrom: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var downtimeTo: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet var collectionOfCommunicationLabels: Array<UILabel>!
    
    
    func applyTheme() {
        for i in 0..<collectionOfCommunicationLabels.count {
        collectionOfCommunicationLabels[i].textColor = Theme.current.textColor
            collectionOfCommunicationLabels[i].backgroundColor = Theme.current.backgroundColor
        }
        backgroundcontentView.backgroundColor = Theme.current.backgroundColor
        CommunicationType.textColor = Theme.current.textColor
        subject.textColor = Theme.current.textColor
        partnerType.textColor = Theme.current.textColor
        partnerID.textColor = Theme.current.textColor
        effectiveFrom.textColor = Theme.current.textColor
        effectiveTo.textColor = Theme.current.textColor
        downtimeFrom.textColor = Theme.current.textColor
        downtimeTo.textColor = Theme.current.textColor
//        backgroundButton.backgroundColor = Theme.current.backgroundColor
        
    }
    

    
    func setCommunication(communication: Communication) {
        CommunicationType.text = communication.communicationType
        subject.text = communication.subject
        partnerType.text = communication.partnerType
        partnerID.text = communication.partnerID
        effectiveFrom.text = communication.effectiveFrom
        effectiveTo.text = communication.effectiveTo
        downtimeFrom.text = communication.downtimeFrom
        downtimeTo.text = communication.downtimeTo
        applyTheme()
        
    }
    
}
```

I've tried almost every answer on stack overflow and nothing has worked for me.

Comment: Use tableView delegate didSelectRowAt indexPath instead of using buttons as a background view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try to implement the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in addition to the cellForRowAtIndexPath method? In that case, you will not need a background button and also you will get a callback in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method on tapping any row in the tableview.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    selectCell.backgroundColor = .red //change to any color you want it to change to on selection
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "CommunicationSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: What do I put instead of the background button then? How would I call the function to preform segue.

Comment: @BobStone You can add it in the same method mentioned above (I have edited it accordingly)

Comment: I tried this and the backgroundColor still isn't changing.

Comment: Try removing the background button and background content view for you to be able to see it

Comment: I figured it out. I used the didhighlight and didunhighlight to do the color changes but still used selected for the segue change. The big problem was the button. I’ll still upvote for sort of leading me to the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped in someway at least